# Problems generating pdf Android

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I'm having trouble creating a PDF file and save it on SD, and would like someone suggested to me what to do, follow what I started doing, if they have any examples, I am grateful for sending me!

My class that tries to generate the PDF:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    private static String FILE = "sdcard/exaple.pdf";
    private static final String TAG = "documentPDF"; 

/**
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tela_relatorio);
    File Directory = new File(FILE); 
    try { 
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(Directory));
        document.open();
        document.addAuthor("Name Author");
        addTitlePage(document);
        document.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}

private void addTitlePage(Document document)throws DocumentException {
    Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
    preface.add(new Paragraph("Document Title", null));
    document.add(preface);
document.newPage();
}
}
```

Comment: Need more information, errors, and where did this PdfWriter class come from? "I am having trouble creating a PDF file and save it on SD" is not enough information :).

Comment: I reformatted your code and removed some of what I hope were typeos.  You had tabs in your post.  Tabs are bad, m'kay.  Use spaces.  Please.

Comment: I think the problem here is getting the thing to compile in the first place.  1) iText (that is iText you're using, right?) doesn't work on Android, unless you get the special commercial license version.  2) lots of what looked like typeos but may have been bugs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Also, are you using this library for your pdf functionality? http://sourceforge.net/projects/apwlibrary/

I'm gonna take a shot at this and try to answer the best I can. A few notes though that could really help your application development is to first use proper code spacing. Since this is an Android question, I imagine that you are developing in Eclipse, but a little known, yet awesome shortcut is to type `Ctrl+A` to select all your code then use `Ctrl+I` which will properly align your code so that it is more readable. In this case, I was able to find out a few things that *MIGHT* not be what you wanted

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tela_relatorio);
    File Directory = new File(FILE); 
    try { 
        //so here you  call your variable "document" but later...
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(Directory));
        // you reference it as documento These are not the same but it looks like they should be
        documento.open();
        document.addAuthor("Name Author");
        addTitlePage(document);
        document.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

private void addTitlePage(Document document)throws DocumentException {
    Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
    preface.add(new Paragraph("Document Title", null));
    //once again, what is this supposed to reference to?
    documento.add(preface);
    documento.newPage();

}
```

So, I don't know enough about the specific libraries involved to offer much more advice than that yet, but once again, there are somethings in there that you might not want. The other problem was your `try` statement wasn't surrounding enough code there. :) Look closely at what you are trying to do, and then think about how that should be done.

Anyway, I think this should at minimum get rid of any compile-time errors, *provided that you have the appropriate imports*. Oh, another handy shortcut if you are using Eclipse is `Ctrl+Shift+I` It will manage your import statements and help you find that packages you need to import. From there, you will need to find any bugs that aren't related to compile errors

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tela_relatorio);
    File Directory = new File(FILE); 
    try { 
        Document document = new Document();

        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(Directory));
        document.open();
        document.addAuthor("Name Author");
        addTitlePage(document);
        document.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

private void addTitlePage(Document document) throws DocumentException {
    Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
    preface.add(new Paragraph("Document Title", null));
    document.add(preface);
    document.newPage();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Staff was able to generate a PDF in android, there is my code already generating a pdf report from the database!
bye!

```
        public ArrayList<Visitantes> RelatorioPDF() {
    Document documento = new Document();
    ArrayList<Visitantes> lista = null;
    try {String sql_innerJoin = "SELECT Visitantes.id, Visitantes.nome, Visitantes.cpf, Visitantes.contato, Visitantes.foto"
                + " FROM Visitantes ";

        Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql_innerJoin, null);
        // Cursor c = getReadableDatabase().query(t,VisitantesDB.COLUNAS,
        // null, null, null, null, null,null);
        PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator +"testeVisitante.pdf"));
        documento.open();
        documento.addAuthor("Tiago");

        lista = new ArrayList<Visitantes>();

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Visitantes visitante = new Visitantes();
            visitante.setId(c.getInt(0));
            visitante.setCpf(c.getString(1));
            visitante.setNome(c.getString(2));
            visitante.setContato(c.getString(3));
            visitante.setFoto(c.getString(4));
            documento.add(new Paragraph("Id:"+visitante.getId()));
            documento.add(new Paragraph("CPF:"+visitante.getCpf()));
            documento.add(new Paragraph("nome:"+visitante.getNome()));
            documento.add(new Paragraph("Contato:"+visitante.getContato()));
            documento.add(new Paragraph("|____________________________________|"));

            lista.add(visitante);
        }
        c.close();
        documento.addCreationDate();
        documento.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("erro", e.toString());

    }
    return lista;
}
```